# Is there away to return all the items from a table as one entry in a query

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I know there is away to do this...I just can't remember (too many programming languages in my head...and I may be dis-remembering something else)
I have this query

this issue I'm having it is returning the cartesian set of the data.

For example... if the person has 5 roles and 5 emails
I will get 25 rows for that person.

Isn't there a way to get all the emails to return as one item,  and all the roles as one item...

I think there is ....I just can't remember

CODE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 saturn.spriden.spriden_id                                          AS cwid,
 saturn.spriden.spriden_first_name                                  AS "first_name",
 saturn.spriden.spriden_last_name                                   AS "last_name",
 gobtpac.gobtpac_external_user                                      AS "username",
 '***-**-'
 || substr(saturn.spbpers.spbpers_ssn, - 4)                          AS "ssn",
 to_char(saturn.spbpers.spbpers_birth_date, 'MON-DD-YYYY')          AS "dob",
 saturn.spbpers.spbpers_pref_first_name                             AS "prefname",
 general.goremal.goremal_email_address                              AS "email",
 general.gorirol.gorirol_role                                       AS "Role",
 general.gobintl.gobintl_passport_id                                AS "Passport ID",
 payroll.pebempl.pebempl_last_work_date                             AS "contract end date"
FROM
      gobtpac
 INNER JOIN saturn.spriden ON gobtpac.gobtpac_pidm = saturn.spriden.spriden_pidm
 INNER JOIN saturn.spbpers ON saturn.spriden.spriden_pidm = saturn.spbpers.spbpers_pidm
 LEFT JOIN general.goremal ON saturn.spriden.spriden_pidm = general.goremal.goremal_pidm
 LEFT JOIN general.gorirol ON saturn.spriden.spriden_pidm = general.gorirol.gorirol_pidm
 LEFT JOIN general.gobintl ON saturn.spriden.spriden_pidm = general.gobintl.gobintl_pidm
 LEFT JOIN payroll.pebempl ON saturn.spriden.spriden_id = payroll.pebempl.pebempl_pidm
WHERE
 saturn.spriden.spriden_id LIKE ( '%' )
 AND upper(saturn.spriden.spriden_last_name) LIKE ( '%' )
 AND saturn.spriden.spriden_change_ind IS NULL
 AND general.goremal.goremal_emal_code IN ( 'CO', 'AL', 'OK', 'BU', 'PE' )
 AND general.goremal.goremal_status_ind = 'A'
 AND general.gorirol.gorirol_role_group = 'INTCOMP'
ORDER BY
 "last_name",
 "first_name",
 cwid,
 "Role"
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` to consolidate rows, and then `LIST_AGG()` or `STRING_AGG()` functions to assemble a single string with all values per group. Which database are you using? The specific solution highly depends on the engine.

Comment: Depending on RDBMS List_Agg(), String_Agg() For XML Path(), Connect by Prior.  group_concat... to name a few.

Comment: The data source  is from Ellucian Banner .. and I'm trying to make a single query for Ellucian Pagebuilder 
this issues is that both goremal  and gorirol are one-to-many

I'll look up those funtions

Comment: Ellucian Banner looks to be a University ERP system as the application/program.  It and looks like it can run on many different RDBMS platforms.  So without knowing the RDBMS, we don't know the available functions.  if there's an equilvant to one of the above in the RDBMS of choice; than that's the answer.